# SDK/API level upgrade issues in Expo/React-Native

Tags: react-native, expo

After I received a message on Google Play about upgrading the API level for my app. I have updated my Expo SDK 47 to 49 version. The app worked well on Expo Go but when I built it into a standalone app (APK) it did not work on Android which has an API level lower than level 33. When I try to open it, it closes itself.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who wanted to help me!
I solved it myself! The issue was due to the deprecated package eas-cli. I removed this and node_modules and reinstalled packages with npm install and npm update.